# Problemas con peticion Post desde Django

Tags: django, post, python-requests

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola buenas! estoy desarrollando un ejercicio de tipo entrevista laboral donde debo hacer una petición POST a una api(list) dentro de la pagina del gobierno. El asunto es que la api solo requiere peticiones post ademas tiene un "response" bastante largo en formato json. hasta ahi todo normal. Por supuesto quiero obtener una respuesta del servidor mas alla del simple "200" si no que me devuelva los valores que requiero. basicamente copie y pegue el response de la pagina para hacer la solicitud pero todo el tiempo me dice que no tiene nada que devolver. realmente e intentado de todo pero siempre dice lo mismo, no tiene nada que devolver, entonces para que esta el response?? les dejo el codigo por supuesto un abrazo a cualquiera q pueda prestarme sus conocimientos

como se aprecia en la imagen finalmente tuve que ponerle distintos if elif else para ver si tenia almenos algo que mostrar pero la respuesta siempre fue que no tenia nada para mostrar. ahi esta la url tambien por si alguien me explica q esta pasando

probe todos los consejos de AI dentro de codestudio. probe cambiar el cuerpo de mi peticion cientos de veces. probe usar el json en paginas como postman donde siempre me dio respuesta 200. el asunto aqui es q no devuelve nada

Comment: Hola Dr. KU, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código y los mensajes de error (si es que los recibes) en formato texto, y que nos expliques en que falla, mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!